# Will our daughter get a dependent Thai visa if the parents are traveling to Thailand for a language course?

Tags: thailand, children

A married couple from Israel is going to Thailand to study Thai for nine months each on an ED visa. What visa, if any, will their baby daughter receive in order to stay in Thailand for the same amount of time?

Comment: I don't know if I'd consider "less than a year" to be long-term residency.

Comment: @Martha The OP asked about a nine-month stay. The Travel.SE Help Page says questions about staying in the country, or complications in every day life due to living in a foreign country as a non-citizen should be asked on Expatriates. The Expatriates "What can I ask here" Help Page welcomes "Questions about work, residence, student, investor and similar mid and long term visas aimed for staying in the country for more time than a tourist or short term business visa would allow." For a nine-month stay, Expatriates seems a better fit.

Comment: Typically in this situation a family member would be given some kind of ‘dependent’ visa, on the basis of the parents’ visa

Comment: A quick web search indicates that a non-immigrant O visa would be the correct one. They'll want a letter from the school and documents proving your relationship (birth certificate in this case) as well as other documents relating to you, the school and your ED visa.